# Prevent a user who created the table from deleting records in SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle

i am new to SQL and Database world, i know basic things. i got this question:

---

Create three users in a database e.g. userA, userB and userC and 
grant basic privileges to create tables and execute the code.  Create 
any table (T1), by connecting to the database as userA. As a "System" user give the following permissions to userA 
and userB:

 UserA should be able to insert and update records on table 
T1
 UserB can access the table T1 records for read only purpose.

 Both userA and userB should not be able to delete records 
from table T1.

---

My solusiton:

```
Create user userA
identified by userA;
```

__

```
Create user userB
identified by userB;
```

__

```
Create user userC
identified by userC;
```

__

```
Create Table T1(
tid number(3) primary key,
tname varchar2(20),
);

insert into T1 Values (8, Mike);
```

__
my solution to first two questions:

```
Grant Insert ON T1 FROM userA;
Grant Update ON T1 FROM userA;

Grant Select on T1 from UserB;
```

__

i solved the first two questions, however, my concern is about the third question, as i didn't find any working answer, but i got a clue after searching that i have to use something called Trigger, i have tried some but with no luck at all. the records are always deleted by both users after trying several grant commands and revoke commands with no luck.

Please help me in using triggers
Thank You

Comment: if you want to prevent deleting records why you wanted to use trigger?

Comment: you are using what database ? please tag correctly ! By the way, this seems like homework to me

Comment: Don't tag this with every database under the sun, focus on the one you're actually using.

Comment: @reds When i use revoke statement, the row keep being deleted. i want help in using trigger for prevent the deletion.

Comment: @Squirrel oracle10g/sql*plus, i didn't find any way to prevent the deletion of the rows, even by using the revoke statement; the rows keep being deleted. Can you help me please.

Comment: I don't think you can revoke those privileges from the owner of the table. The typical way to deal with this, is to use a different database user for schema management (DDL) and data management (DML). See e.g. here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13349/1822

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authorization.htm#DBSEG99960

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php

```
REVOKE DELETE ON T1 FROM user1, user2;
```

The other way would be changing the ownership of the table as a post procedure before revoking delete

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/Change-table-ownership-and-properties-in-less-than-a-minute

Comment: That will not prevent a row from being deleted, i have tried it. rows keep being deleted. that is why i want to use trigger.

Comment: which user was able to delete the rows?

Comment: User1.. the same user who crated the table.

Comment: You can't revoke permissions from the owner of the table. If you really want to maintain that logic, i can only suggest the use of triggers.

Comment: Since i faced this question, i am trying to use triggers, but the solution i got using triggers is to restore the deleted record/s, but that will not prevent the user from deleting the record. @RenatoAfonso

Comment: @Khaledtaj8 deleting without committing the batch will not delete the row. in trigger i reckon you should be able to rollback the batch if you don't want this user to delete the row

Answer (score 0):

Do not use triggers. Triggers are not meant to prevent deletes.

You should not need to revoke deletes because you never granted them. They should innately not be able to delete records. This makes me think that you are creating T1 as the user itself. If that's the case, you cannot revoke the delete from the owner of the table.